# Hadoop:Why my active namenode use too much memory?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

In the 50070 monitor web page,It shows:

```
16,889,283 files and directories, 9,236,314 blocks = 26,125,597 total filesystem object(s).

Heap Memory used 14.84 GB of 25.85 GB Heap Memory. Max Heap Memory is 25.85 GB.
```

[confusion-over-hadoop-namenode-memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211548/confusion-over-hadoop-namenode-memory-usage) tells me how to calculate the memory of namenode used.I find the method is not for me. `26,125,597` * `150byte` ≈ `4G`,but i use near `15G` memory!

But,the standby namenode just use `5G` memory.

```
16,889,283 files and directories, 9,236,314 blocks = 26,125,597 total filesystem object(s).
Heap Memory used 4.9 GB of 25.85 GB Heap Memory. Max Heap Memory is 25.85 GB.
```